# jQuery result not displaying in field

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I just can't get this result to display in the field using an `id`. It worked fine using a `class` but it just refuses to work using an `id`.

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pbe4b/15/

Works fine:

```
<input id="button123" placeholder="number here"></input>
<span class="output123"></span>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<input id="button123" placeholder="number here"></input>
<input id="output123"></input>
```

Would love any help!

Comment: Shouldn't the second one be a span instead of an input?  It changed it to a span in your fiddle and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/pbe4b/16/

Comment: Hi @SLoW. Yes, works fine with a `span` but I want it to be an `id` as it works better for my project. Sorry, probably should have made that clearer in the question.

Comment: You can assign an id to a span

Comment: @verrucktfuchs Like Phillip said, you can assign an ID to a span, which is what I did in that fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$('#output123').val()
```

instead of

```
$('#output123').html()
```

`input` is self closing tag so you should use `val()` to get value from this .

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with a class/id, it is due to the fact you changed the element.

inputs do not have `html()`, you use `val()` to set the value.

Cleaned up code without all the copy and paste:

```
$('#button123').keyup(function(){
    var n = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    var calc;
    if(n <= 35000) {
        calc = n/100*70;
    } else if(n <= 45000) {
        calc = n/100*75;
    } else {
        calc = n/100*80;
    }
    var val = numberWithCommas(calc.toFixed(2));
    $('#output123').val(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have changed spans to inputs, and so `.html()` is no longer valid. The selector is fine. Change all instances of `.html()` to `.val()`.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="button123" placeholder="number here"></input>
<input id="output123"></input>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#button123').keyup(function(){
var n = parseInt($(this).val());

if(n <= 35000) {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*70).toFixed(2)));
}
else if(n <= 45000) {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*75).toFixed(2)));
}
else {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*80).toFixed(2)));
}
})
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbe4b/17/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pbe4b/19/

Vals instead of HTML since it is an input

```
$('#button123').keyup(function(){
var n = parseInt($(this).val());

if(n <= 35000) {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*70).toFixed(2)));
}
else if(n <= 45000) {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*75).toFixed(2)));
}
else {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*80).toFixed(2)));
}
})
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button123').keyup(function(){
var n = parseInt($(this).val());

if(n <= 35000) {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*70).toFixed(2)));
}
else if(n <= 45000) {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*75).toFixed(2)));
}
else {
    $('#output123').val(numberWithCommas((n/100*80).toFixed(2)));
}
})
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#output123').val()` to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

To set the **value** of a **input** use:

JS:

```
document.getElementById('output123').value = 'my value';
```

jQuery:

```
$('#output123').val('my value');
```

.html is used to replace the inner content of an item, in the case of input you need to change an attribute.